# Clear mounted html in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have 2 components. I have some checkboxes in first component.It resides in left side of the Web Page like Nav bar.  In second component I would like to load some HTML Div element on the basis of those checkbox. Now I can load the divs while clicking on those checkboxes using below code.

```
mounted () {
        EventBus.$on('change',this.formated);
    },
```

But when I am clicking on a new checkboxes the loaded divs of previous checkboxes will not disappear. I can see both output of current and previous checkboxes as like output of `.append()` of jQuery.

How can I clear/disappear previous HTML outputs ?

Answer (score 1):

You need use jQuery's `clear()` on the elements innerHTML which you're appending too. A better approach would be to instead of appending content, use a `v-for` directive and maintain an array in the data property with the content you want visible. That would be leveraging vue's reactivity for its intended purposes and offer a more flexible implementation.